# ZF: Difference between POW and SEP?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

In ZF, the Power Set Axiom (POW) says that given any set $A$, there exists a set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ such that
$$
\forall a(a\in\mathcal{P}(A)\leftrightarrow a\subseteq A)\tag{1}
$$

> **Questions**:
>
> 1. On many occasions, I've seen POW stated like this: "For any set $A$ there is a set consisting of all subsets of $A$."
>
>    Would a more precise formulation be: "For any set $A$ *which is known to exist* there exists a set containing all subsets of $A$ *which are known to exist*."?
> 2. An instance of the Axiom Schema of Separation (SEP) essentially gives the existence of a subset of a given set. So, why doesn't POW imply SEP? Is it because POW doesn't give the existence of the individual subsets but only the set containing them all?
> 3. Conversely, does SEP and the remaining ZF axioms imply POW?

Comment: What would a $\textit{non-existing}$ set be?

Comment: How does the axiom schema of separation give the existence of *all* elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$, given a set $A$?

Comment: @T_M A non-existing set would be a set whose existence can't be proved from the ZF axioms, for example the "set" of all sets?

Comment: @Guest In formulation of POW only sets are involved. Not "sets".

Comment: But the set of all sets isn't a set. This doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. So the formulation of SEP is ok, "for all $\textit{sets}$ there exists...". Existence of the set of all sets isn't the issue here, the issue is that it's not an actual set.

Comment: SEP only "produces" subsets of sets that are allready known. This is not the case for POW. So SEP does not imply POW.

Comment: @Guest The axiom schema of separation ensures that for a given set $x$, $\mathcal{P}(x)$ exists as a subclass of the universe. However, it is only with POW can you deduce that it is also a set.

Comment: @ZeroXLR No, in ZF it does not.

Comment: @ZeroXLR please edit the Weierstrass p symbol you used for the partitive set of $x$. Use \mathcal{P}(A).

Comment: @T_M The terminology "existing set" I used should really mean "set which we have proved to exist according to the ZF axioms". As I understand it, we have the existence of the empty set (either as an axiom or as a consequence of the Axiom of Infinity, for example), and from this set alone we build all the other sets from the axioms. I mean, isn't ZF supposed to tell us what sets there *really* are?

Comment: @drhab "SEP only 'produces' subsets of sets that are already known. This is not the case for POW" As I understand, POW is supposed to give the existence of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ for a given set $A$. But, that set $A$ that we use in POW should have been showed to exist before using it, no?

Comment: @Guest Yes, that's right. But $\wp(A)$ is not a *subset* of a set that has been shown to exist. That's different for SEP: only *subsets* of sets that have been shown to exist.

Comment: @drhab It is not, but if SEP is able to separate all subsets of a given set, then it is not immediately clear to me why the other axioms couldn't be used to *construct* $\mathcal{P}(A)$ from its members.

Comment: Only by means of the axioms POW, SUB and PAIR sets are constructed that have a higher *rank* than the sets used by construction. It might be that you are not familiar with rank yet, but if you go on studying sets it will cross your road.

Comment: Axioms codify *basic properties*. Like how municipal laws codify how a building *should* look like. But then when you get to the actual structure, you will find that even if inside a house the basic idea is similar (kitchen, beds, living room, shower), the execution can be very different and that two structures can look entirely different from one another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1:** Axioms do not have any sense of time or knowledge. They *can't speak* about whether sets or other elements exist prior to (or as a consequence of) other sets -- at least not then in standard first-order logic that axiomatic set theory is usually done within.

It may be *intuitively instructive* to imagine all of the sets of set theory to come into being in some particular order sequence, guided by "when" axioms say they ought to exist, but that is not what the axioms *say*.

What the axioms *say* is just "Let's imagine we have a universe of sets, and such-and-such claims *happen to be true* about the universe of sets we have". The axiom of power sets does not *create* a power set -- it simply *asserts* that there *is* a power set of whatever you hold in your hand, and this power set *has existed the whole time*. It comes together with all of the other sets in your universe, and the *entire* totality of sets magically happens to make your axioms true.

---

**2:** What the power set axiom says is only that for every set $A$ there's a set whose members are those sets *in the universe* that happen to be subsets of $A$. It doesn't say anything about how many such things exist -- all it tells you that there's a set $\mathcal P(A)$ such that *if* you manage to find some set $B$ and discover that $B\subseteq A$, the set you have found will also be an element of $\mathcal P(A)$.

On the other hand, the axiom of separation *can*, in most variants of the formulations, be derived from the axiom of *replacement* (together with the axiom of the empty set).

---

**3:** The axiom of separation lets you know that any subcollection of a set that you can define (in the language of set theory) will exist as a set inside your universe of sets. It does **not** in itself guarantee that there's a **set** that contain all of those subsets; for that you need a separate axiom.

For example, if you take a model of ZFC and restrict it to only the hereditarily finite-or-countable sets, you will have something that satisfies all axioms of ZFC *except for* the power set axiom. Thus, the other axioms cannot (if they are consistent) imply the power set axiom.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer raises more questions in my mind, though. (a) If I understand, we have 'the' intuitive class of all sets in mind and the main reason why we use the axioms is to make sure we have a set with the desired properties in our class (for example, we use the axioms to make sure that in any model of ZF there is a set behaving like $\mathbb{R}$)? (b) Since there are many models of ZF, when we talk about sets, do we talk about the (intuitive) union of all these models, if that makes any sense?

Comment: (c) Also, what if in my model I have the set $A$ of all cats in Florida. Cats are not set, so for every set $B$ we have $B\not\in A$ and $A$ acts like an empty set? But the empty set should be unique according to ZF, and the set $C$ of all cats in Egypt also acts like the empty set in my model and clearly $A\neq C$...

Comment: (a) Formally we don't "use the axioms to make sure we have a set". We use the axioms to build proofs. The axioms are what we already (think we) know about the model, and then proofs allow us to know _more_ things about it. (b) Usually we leave it implicitly that we're working in _some_ model of ZFC, and leave it to the reader to decide which one _he_ wants to think of. As long as the model he chooses to think of satisfies the axioms that we work from, he can be sure that what we say is true about it.

Comment: @Guest, (c) Something that contains a set of all cats in Florida _cannot be a model of ZF_, for the reason you sketch. ZF is designed to talk about universes where everything we ever want to speak formally about sets. If you want to speak directly about things that are _not_ sets, ZF is not the axiom system you should be using.