# Can we create all subsets of all sets?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Using only axiom of specification, can we create ***all possible*** subsets of ***any*** set?

For finite sets, it’s true I guess. But for infinite sets, what can we say? If it were true of infinite sets, we’d have not needed the axiom of powers.

But we *do* need that. Does that imply that statements of first-order logic are not enough to create (via specification) *all* the subsets of infinite sets?

Comment: The Power ser axiom (as per your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276820/why-is-axiom-of-powers-needed)) is needed in order to assert that **the set of all subsets** of a set $A$ exists, i.e. that we can collect **all** subsets of $A$ into a single set $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: When you say "create" do you mean *define* it ? In order to do this, we can use *Specification axiom*, using a formula that "specifies" the corresponding subset of $A$.

Comment: Your argument about a finite set is also wrong. If you have non-standard integers, then they are internally finite, but externally they are infinite sets. And the induction that you have in mind is external, so it does not apply to non-standard finite sets anyway. But it's worse than that. Specification allow parameters.

Comment: Also, to add on what @Mauro has been writing, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446509/zf-difference-between-pow-and-sep might be relevant for your recent questions.